# How does Gideon know the suspect is driving an American made truck?

Tags: plot-explanation, criminal-minds

In season 1 episode 1, *Criminal Minds*, Gideon is giving a lecture at FBI academy, he mentions the killer they are looking for exhibits the following traits:

- Stutters, Gideon explains stuttering is the reason why the killer only picks up people from remote locations due to lack of confidence and feels shameful of being stuttering.
- Owns an American made truck and it is in disrepair. How does Gideon reach this conclusion? It has never been explained.